# Adding The Results Of Two Queries In Pandas Dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, hive, jupyter-notebook, presto

I am trying to do data analysis for the first time using Pandas in a Jupyter notebook and was wondering what I am doing wrong.

I have created a data frame for the results of a query to store a table that represents the total population I am comparing to.

| ds | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-28-9 | 100 |
| 2022-27-9 | 98 |
| 2022-26-9 | 99 |
| 2022-25-9 | 98 |

This data frame is called total_count

I have created a data frame for the results of a query to store a table that represents the count of items that are out of SLA to be divided by the total.

| ds | oo_sla |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-28-9 | 60 |
| 2022-27-9 | 38 |
| 2022-26-9 | 25 |
| 2022-25-9 | 24 |

This data frame is called out_of_sla

These two data sets are created by Presto queries from Hive tables if that matters.

I am now trying to divide those results to get a % out of SLA but I am getting errors.

```
data = {"total_count"[], "out_of_sla"[]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["result"] = [out_of_sla]/[total_count]
print(df)
```

I am getting an error for invalid syntax on line 3. My goal was to create a trend of in/out of sla status and a widget for the most recent datestamps sla. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: update your question with full script and actual error received.

Comment: Are those four lines of code your actual code and not pseudocode? The first three lines are the only ones that should do anything. (FYI about the fourth line, for examining a Pandas dataframe in Jupyter, you'd either just put `df` as the last line in a cell or use `display(df)`.) It's impossible to tell how the first line would work because you don't actually show how you assign `total_count` and `out_of_sla`, but since you say there are dataframes, I don't see how, for example, you'd you be referencing the first one as `"total_count"[]`? My confusion continues from there. I assume you are ...

Comment: <continuing> trying to combine the two dataframes given the second line? Does that work before you try the third line? You could easily check and share the results. (If it doesn't work, have you looked at [Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html).) The third line. Now you are using something totally different than the first line of your shared code, and so that is cofusing. But I would actually expect `out_of_sla` and `total_count` to be dataframes from before any code you've shared? True? And why are you bracketing the names of them?